# How to set email field type value to a string

Tags: apex

I can set Email(ExternalId) field type value to a string. But when i am trying to set the Email field type value to a string it is not getting assigned.

My code is :

```
String a = account.PersEmail__c; //(Email External Id field)
if(condition){
  String a = account.MyEMailId__c;  //(Email Id field)
}
```

Please prvide me solution !! Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below code in Developer Console and it worked as expected.

User u = [SELECT Email,Id,Name FROM User where Name = 'Test User'];

String email = u.Email;

system.debug('email...'+email);

The debug prints the correct value retrieved from the SOQL.
Looks like **account.MyEMailId__c** is null and hence null value is getting assigned to the String a. Put a null check in the if block and it will work for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Do this

```
String a = account.PersEmail__c; //(Email External Id field)
if(condition && account.MyEMailId__c != null){
  String a = String.valueOf(account.MyEMailId__c);  //(Email Id field)
}
```

you can assign the value.